# How to Filter Email Address NOT LIKE not working

Tags: mysql, select

I am working on a mysql database and I am trying to select and not use emails that are @gmail or @yahoo and stuff. I am using the following select

```
select 1stBusPocEmail
     , PhysicalAddressZipPostalCode  
  from contractors 
 where 1stBusPocEmail NOT like '%aol.com' 
    or 1stBusPocEmail NOT like '%AOL.COM' 
    or 1stBusPocEmail NOT like '%bellsouth.net' 
    or 1stBusPocEmail NOT like '%GMAIL.COM' 
    or 1stBusPocEmail NOT like '%yahoo.com' 
    or 1stBusPocEmail NOT like '%gmail.com' 
    or 1stBusPocEmail NOT like '%hotmail.com' 
    or 1stBusPocEmail NOT like '%.gov' 
   and PhysicalAddressZipPostalCode like '327%' 
    or PhysicalAddressZipPostalCode like '328%' 
   and BusinessTypeString NOT LIKE '%A2%' 
   and BusinessTypeString NOT LIKE '%A5%' 
   and BusinessTypeString NOT LIKE '%OY%' 
   and BusinessTypeString NOT LIKE '%QF%'  
 order 
    by rand() 
 limit 50 ;
```

I do this and it works pretty well but a few gmails are still getting through. here is a sample output

```
 +---------------------------------+------------------------------+
| 1stBusPocEmail                  | PhysicalAddressZipPostalCode |
+---------------------------------+------------------------------+
| sholomt@gmail.com               | 60030                        |
| shaynes@briggs.k12.ok.us        | 74464                        |
| alon@seamedive.net              | 33317                        |
| jmurray@foxsubacute.com         | 17055                        |
| msmith@g2klabs.com              | 20151                        |
| vk@vektroncorp.com              | 18966                        |
| lberczel@heritage-collision.com | 48197                        |
| christy.brudin@gmail.com        | 22043                        |
| gjesclard@hotmail.com           | 99516                        |
| lee.fuller@fullerlabs.net       | 92831                        |
  +---------------------------------+------------------------------+
10 rows in set (7.67 sec)
```

Comment: The astute use of parentheses is required to make sense of this query: (3 x 2) + 1 is not the same as 3 x (2+1)

Comment: Always use parentheses when you mix AND and OR, the default grouping is rarely what you intend.

Comment: Also, you usually want `AND` when you're combining multiple `NOT LIKE`  or `!=` conditions.

Comment: `sholomt@gmail.com` is not like `%aol.com`, so it matches the condition.

Comment: thank you all that helped a lot.